# Why we are declaring the class as abstract class it has only concrete methods in it?

Tags: java, abstraction

Abstract class means, it has both abtract methods and concrete methods but even if it has only concrete methods, it is just look like a normal methods only right. 
And why we are declaring the class as the abstract without any abtract methods?

Comment: NO, abstract means it is abstract, that is not complete, not to be instanciated - if a class has an abstract method it must be abstract, but not an abstract class must not have abstract methods.Specificatoin [8.1.1.1. abstract Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.1): "An abstract class is a class that is incomplete, or to be **considered incomplete**."

Answer (score 2):

On some cases, you do want to have some shared logic/fields/methods between several classes, but you do not want the base class to be instanciated by itself, only the extending classeses.

For such use-cases, abstract class, even without any abstract methods, can do the trick

Comment: or one could follow composition over inheritance instead.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a base class for implementing some interfaces: all methods are concrete, but not all methods of interfaces are implemented.